c# Channel Writer when closed
I'm using C# Channels in important performance environment (using as camera frame buffer). As I have been testing is the fastest option to do that.
I have a little doubt on how to close the Channel.
I have a producer thread which is adding elements to channel, but If I unsuscribe to an event I want to close the channel to free resources and remove the consummer task.
The key here is how to close the channel without having exceptions when other thread have to write on the Channel.
private event EventHandler<> _frameSetEvent;
public event EventHandler<> FrameSetEvent
{
    add
    {
        StartBmpFrameBuffer();
        _frameSetEvent += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        _frameSetEvent -= value;
        _frameBuffer.CloseBuffer(); //Channel Complete
    }
}

I can check before adding, but I don't know really the performance impact on the if check
public async Task AddItemAsync(T item)
{
    if (_bufferRunning)
        await _mainChannel.Writer.WriteAsync(item);
}

Here is my code to add. I think that maybe in the sentences after the if the close buffer can come from other thread and make the adding fail (if remove the checking on the add)
private async Task AddCamFrameSet2BmpBuffer(CvCameraFrameSetEvtArgs camFrameSet)
{
    if (_frameSetEvent != null)
    {
        if (_frameBuffer == null)
            return;

        //Some code (not too long) (maybe 1-2 ms)
        await _frameBuffer.AddItemAsync(camVisionFrameSet);
    }
}

I was asking because maybe there is a better and efficient way to close the channel without having problems with producer.


I can check before adding, but I don't know really the performance impact on the if check

The first thing here you should be concerned here is not the performance but validity of the approach - check and subsequent call without synchronization (like "locking" with semaphore for example) are not atomic, so if another thread can close the writer then it can do that after the if (_bufferRunning) check is done but before the write happens, resulting in error. So you need either to perform some kind of synchronization or add error handling (though in theory adding such check can reduce number of errors thrown, depended on the use case).
In some cases you can consider using ChannelWriter<T>.TryWrite(T) which will not result in the error if the channel is closed, it is not async though.
Without seeing the full code it is hard to tell, but before looking for the fastest solution possible I would recommend to validate that this particular place is an actual bottleneck and/or in the hot path, potentially having some exceptions silenced should not be a big problem for app performance if it happens relatively rarely, so if unsubscribing happens not that often - I would argue that it is ok to have some exceptions muted (though you should stop the AddCamFrameSet2BmpBuffer invocations on unsubscribing or use the  _bufferRunning handling approach, again - without full code it's a bit hard to tell)

AddCamFrameSet2BmpBuffer method should not be stopped if exceptions thrown because the method do more things that should be done, but you are right that this buffer it's not so important so I can loose items.
Maybe it's better to use WaitToWriteAsync() with this method the execution won't pass inside the if and won't try to add items
